# X days after per each date in a list

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to consider a list of dates

```
 dates=['10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/30/2020',
 '10/29/2020']
```

which are input in the following code:

```
for t in dates:
    t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
    start_date =  t + timedelta(2) 
    day = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

but it returns a `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime` here:

```
---> 11     day = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I would like to consider, as start_date, two days after the selected date; e.g., if I have 10/30/2020, I would consider 11/1/2020.
Ca you please tell me how to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` converts a string to a `datetime` object, `strftime` converts a `datetime` object to a string. Your `day` should be converting back to a string, so you should use `strftime`:

```py
for t in dates:
    t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
    start_date =  t + timedelta(2) 
    # notice strftime instead of strptime
    day = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    print(day) # 11/01/2020 for 10/30/2020 and 10/31/2020 for 10/29/2020
```